# script to output event logs not accessing not working

Tags: csv, powershell

I am new to powershell, Need to write a script to pull security logs and then place the data in a time stamped csv file in a location but I am getting I get stuck in a loop.  My desired outcome is a CSV file in my directory with the security logs and time stamp for file name here is what I got for the part it is flagging.

```
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
| Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
| foreach-Object {
    $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
    $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
    $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
    $eventList += $row
    $variable | Export-Csv c:\output.csv
    }
```

$eventList

Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:12 char:21

I am guessing the issue is here?  Again my apologize very little scripting background, just trying to make a process better.

```
$variable | Export-Csv c:\output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't define `$variable` within your script, that is why you getting this exception. It looks like you trying to export a bunch of EventLog entries as csv, so the `Export-Csv` cmdlet probably should belong outside the `Foreach-Object`cmdlet. Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date `
| Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
| foreach-Object {
    $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
    $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
    $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
    $row # this will put the current row to the pipeline 
} | Export-Csv 'c:\output.csv'
```